# Securing a Windows PC

Tags: windows, firewalls, ids

Currently I have an "Antivirus" and Anti Malware software installed.
In addition I closed all remote assistance and unused port rules on my firewall.

I'd really like to get a complete as possible solution/guide.

I wanted to know if there is  a guide on further securing my machine.
Do you have any suggestions? (IDS? Firewall rules etc...)

Note: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Wait, you have an "anti-virus" and "anti-malware" installed? Are they both running at the same time (ie. do they both have real-time protection switched on)?  That's generally not an advisable setup, (among several reasons) the two can interfere with the operations of each other via false positives.  Otherwise...

Comment: ... make sure Windows is set to automatically download & apply security updates.  Make sure your programs/apps/plug-ins--especially common ones like browsers, Flash, Reader, Office, iTunes, etc.--are either auto-updating correctly or that you are periodically checking for updates yourself. Disable or uninstall Java player unless you absolutely must have it.  (Try doing so with Flash too.)  And, yes, upgrade to Windows 10. It has many security improvements vs. 7, including new Windows store apps that are sandboxed (ie. restricted) from doing a lot of bad things in case they are compromised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but this view that Linux is by default more secure than Windows is wrong. Does [GnuTLS](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/03/critical-crypto-bug-leaves-linux-hundreds-of-apps-open-to-eavesdropping/) mean anything to anyone? How about all of the issues in OpenSSL recently? Vulnerabilities affect Linux just as much as Windows. More so in some cases.

In general, as long as you are keeping your OS and applications patched, you are doing the first few things right. Anti-virus and anti-malware help too, as would a software firewall on the machine.

If you want to go into ultra paranoid mode, then have a look at something like Sophos UTM, or purchase a hardware firewall. Ensure that any ports you don't use are blocked both inbound and outbound.

Use something like Norton DNS so that you don't go to known phishing and Malware sites. Install NoScript in your browser and whitelist only sites you trust.

Ensure you have a sound backup strategy with redundant backups and off-site backups.

Just a few things off the top of my head, but this idea that Linux is inherently more secure than Windows is a myth

Answer (score -2):

Also council move to Linux, I probably will describe a couple of programs that will definitely help improve of the home PC a little bit.

1. [Tripwire Secure Cheq](http://www.tripwire.com/securecheq/) - just download and run this app and it will show you some of weak points of your system.
2. Set up enterprise firewall (default sucks, but better than nothing)
3. Enable UAC
4. Install and configure [EMET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2458544) with "maximum" security settings
5. Disable javascript in Chromium(or delete your browser, install Chromium and disable javascript) and allow it only for whitelisted sites (google, yahoo, youtube, etc)
6. Completely delete all the "anti-malware" stuff. Non-enterprise solutions will not provide full security. Actually, enterprise solutions won't either, so what is the reason of paying money?
7. Do not run untrusted executables(i.e. without signature)

And so on. Install linux much easier as you can see.

Comment: Downvote for #1 recommendation being for software that only runs on XP and Server 2003.  Even at the time you posted that, it was horribly outdated.

Comment: @BenVoigt wow, didn't expect that. I remember for sure that I've launched it on my Win7 PC back several years ago.

Comment: It might run, but if it doesn't know about the new configuration options and system settings on the new OS versions, it's useless as a security checkup.  Like running antivirus with decade-old signatures :(

Comment: Your point might take place but in the other hand I didn't bought it so configuration was ultimately stripped by default. Even though this is still better than nothing.